# How to adjust a Timestamp that comes from my database?

Tags: java, date

In the database, a time is saved as a Timestamp in the UTC time zone (that is, 0). When I get it, I need to add the Timezone from the place that I will send. I have these two pieces of information, but I can't find the time.

This is the code from which I get both information. I've tried to transform to `LocalDateTime` and adjust the zone, but it didn't produce any results. There is no much of code:

```
Timestamp timestamp = resultQueryCamerasOffline.getLastOnline();
String zoneId = resultQueryCamerasOffline.getEmpresaTimezone();
System.out.println(timestamp.toString());
System.out.println(zoneId);
```

> 2020-03-12 03:01:45.0
>
> America/São_Paulo

In the database, `last_online` has value:

```
2020-03-12 03:01:45.0
```

Comment: You cannot transform it to a `LocalDateTime` **and** adjust the time zone, because a `LocalDateTime` doesn't have one and won't accept any...

Comment: Understood. So what should I do?

Comment: If you could avoid getting a `Timestamp` in the first place, you should. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead go for for example an `OfsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can and maybe have to use a `LocalDateTime` in order to achieve what you want, but the final product should be a `ZonedDateTime`.

Basically, the timestamp should be converted to a `LocalDateTime` and that `LocalDateTime` can then be converted to a `ZonedDateTime` by adding a specific `ZoneId`, like this:

## Just adding a zone, leaving the datetime as is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get or take a timestamp
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-03-12 03:01:45.0");
    // transforming it into a LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    // now create a ZonedDateTime by putting a zone
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime,
                                                    ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
}
```

The output is

```
2020-03-12T03:01:45-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

If you are sure the client that runs this code always has the desired time zone, then you can alternatively use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` when the `ZonedDateTime` is being created.

**But** if you don't just want to add a zone but really convert the `Instant` to another zone, then you can do this:

## Converting the `Instant` to another time zone:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get or take a timestamp
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-03-12 03:01:45.0");
    // transforming it into a LocalDateTime
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = timestamp.toLocalDateTime();
    // now create a ZonedDateTime by putting a zone
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
            localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+00:00")),
            ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
}
```

This outputs

```
2020-03-12T00:01:45-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

You can have the second one shorter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get or take a timestamp
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-03-12 03:01:45.0");
    // transforming it into a LocalDateTime
    ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.of(timestamp.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // now create a ZonedDateTime by putting a zone
    ZonedDateTime saoPaulo = utc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(saoPaulo);
}
```

The output stays

```
2020-03-12T00:01:45-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

If you want the output formatted differently, you have to either choose one of the built-in patterns (public constants of [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME`) or give it a custom one (by `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String pattern)` plus an optional `Locale`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get or take a timestamp
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf("2020-03-12 03:01:45.0");
    // transforming it into a LocalDateTime
    ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.of(timestamp.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // now create a ZonedDateTime by putting a zone
    ZonedDateTime saoPaulo = utc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
    // create a formatter for your locale and with the desired pattern
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a xxx",
            Locale.forLanguageTag("pt-BR"));
    // and print the result
    System.out.println(saoPaulo.format(dtf));
}
```

This time, the output is formatted in a totally different way:

```
Quinta-feira 12 mar 2020 12:01:45 AM -03:00
```

Comment: But if it's on the database as 03:01:45 at GMT 0, when it be converted to ZoneId America/SaoPaulo (-03:00) it should produce 00:01:45, right?

Comment: @FearX yes, correct... The first example is just the same time plus a zone, I added a conversion example that converts the moment to another zone.

Comment: @FearX you're welcome... How do you want to format it? You can do that with a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @FearX I have added a formatting example... Have a look at it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

get the millis from your timestamp and try:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime
.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp.getTime()), ZoneId.systemDefault(yourTimezone()));
```

or try using a [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)